# How do I use else and if properly on php?

Tags: php

So I have a php file here for registering users,

```
<?php
include_once('connectdb.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['rptpassword'];
$hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM hash WHERE email = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo '<div class="login_stat">Username Already Registered! 
        </div>';
    exit();
}else{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 0) {
        /*$sql = "INSERT INTO `hash`(`email`, `password`, 
        `credits`) VALUES ('$username', '$hashedPwd', '0'); ";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM hash WHERE email=''";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        $sql3 = "CREATE TABLE `$username` (data VARCHAR (256) NOT 
        NULL)";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);*/
        SESSION['username'] = $username
        header( "refresh:5;url=home.php" );
        echo '<div class="login_stat"> You are succesfully 
        registered</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

But whenever i run the page it automatically skips to the `else` tag then running the header and the echo codes. What Am I doing Wrong?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: By "run the page", do you mean without submitting the form? It doesn't seem that `mysqli_num_rows` would ever return *less* than zero.

Comment: Why don't you use the variable `$count` that you declared before the if-statements instead of doing `mysqli_num_rows($result)` all around in your code? And as pointed out by @showdev - The if-statement in your `else`-block makes no sense.

Comment: The page automatically refreshes on register.php because of my incorrect use of else. Even after removing the second `if` statement the website still runs the 2nd condition

Comment: What I mean is, the `header` command should never be executed because `mysqli_num_rows($result)` will never be less than zero. So I don't understand how that's happening.

Comment: @showdev then how do I let the user  know that they are successfully registered then redirecting them to the home.php

Comment: I'd suggest `if ($count>0) { /* exists */ } else { /* doesn't exist */ }`.

Comment: this does not work either, just by proceeding with the registration link shows the SUCCESSFULY REGISTERED without even doing anything

Comment: Are you going to create a new table for each registered user? That's not a good solution. _Specially_ since you don't seem to do any validation on the username. Just have one `data`-table which include a `user_id`-column as reference instead.

Comment: By "proceeding with the registration link" do you mean before or after the `<form>` is submitted?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no sorry i forgot to remove the code that creates a new table for the users. I have a separate table for the user and password

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the username you're trying with actually do exist in the database? If not, then it's no wonder that the `else`-block keeps getting executed. If you're sure that the username already exists, then do a `var_dump($username); exit;` before your `if`-statement and check that it contains what you expect. Double check that none of the usernames (the posted and in the db) don't have any extra spaces before or after.

Comment: @showdev after the form was submitted.

Comment: If you're using `if ($count>0) { /* already exists */ } else { echo "SUCCESSFULLY REGISTERED."; }` and you see the "SUCCESSFULLY REGISTERED" message, then the `$username` value (whatever it may be) doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: @showdev because the command is executed right before the submission of the details of the registrant. That's why I'm thinking if I put... `if the register button is clicked then say registered successfuly` under the first `else` tag. How would I detect the register button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The second if not necessary you could use elsif for error handling and numbur of rows can be equal to 0 so if you wanna use that statement chane if with else if and use `mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0`. Also you have so wide open MySQL injection you have to check propel MySQL security in PHP as @Magnus Eriksson said

> Warning! You are wide open for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. – Magnus Eriksson

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if(!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        $mm = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
if(isset($mm)) {
    SESSION['username'] = $username
    header( "refresh:5;url=home.php" );
    echo '<div class="login_stat"> You are succesfully 
    registered</div>';
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say this does not work. it is not showing the user is registered. Also I am aware that the semicolon is missing on the session tag. Forgot to put it in there

Comment: I added my old code with yours i hope it's help, if it's not you can send me link to try it I can help you with that